# How can I hide the colored plus signs on my texture?

Tags: texture-painting

How can I hide the colored plus signs on my texture?
I have these colored plus signs appearing on my texture/model. 
I haven't figured out a way to hide them.

[image: Cross signes]

The blend file:

[image]

Comment: It looks like UV grid. Can you attach your .blend file to your post?
http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: I cant see any texture in the .blend, only "uvtest". If you are using additional textures in your scene, please pack them into .blend using File->External Data -> Pack all or click the Pack icon next to the image input field.

Comment: This is a copy of the blend file i'm working in. So i use the same texture but in the other version it is painted. 
But essentially the uvtest is the texture i'm painting on.
Is it possible to hide the grid after i created the texture? 
I've found the option to enable the grid but i selected the option when creating the texture. Can i hide it afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your scene so it is ready to paint over the UV grid texture to the new texture (called "stairs").
I basically added this extra texture for both materials and set the texture int the paint slot (left toolbar).

[image]

[image]